# How to implement authentication and authorization using MSAL.net

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Please help me.

To login into Azure active directory how to use MSAL.Net library in my login page of my website.I am seeing very big samples online but I didnt find small peace of code which makes me to understand MSAL.

Comment: what application are you building that needs msal.net authentication?

Comment: I am building  Web asp.net

Answer (score 0):

MSAL Library is just an implementation for enabling developers to acquire tokens from the Microsoft identity platform endpoint.

If you want to use MSAL to acquire a token, you need to:

1. Register an application in Azure AD.
2. Add target API, and grant consent to select permissions.
3. Generate a secret key.

Then you can get a token as [Acquire a token and call Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-windows-desktop).

However, I think what you really want is to integrate AAD. You can easily [enable AAD authentication for your .NET web application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp).  It uses `OWIN` middleware.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a aspnet or aspnetcore, you can get the necessary code needed to sign in your web application with your Azure AD tenant just by following steps.

[Create the sample from the command line](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg#option-2-create-the-sample-from-the-command-line)

Note that MSAL.NET is a token acquisition library (for services like MS Graph and such) that can optionally sign-in users as well. the sign-in code is present in the aspnet and aspnet core SDKs